# Unexplained universal app crash on iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4, universal-binary

we have an iPad app crashing without.  However it is a universal app using the same Views as an iPhone app and the iPhone isn't crashing.  The iPad crashes randomly in the sim and the actual device.  And the Console provides ZERO reason or even that it has stopped working.  Its just blank.  So all i have is a crash report I don't understand.  Please help if you can! Thanks!

> Incident Identifier:
>   E0C2B9A1-7BAB-4D51-998A-5E46F7A210C2
>   CrashReporter Key:
>   7a38ec6be758028f72704776762ed92147621215
>   Hardware Model:      iPad1,1 Process: 
>   PolicePlus [14699] Path:
>   /var/mobile/Applications/4C059F18-BA33-4163-BE3A-B46DF274E63C/PolicePlus.app/PolicePlus
>   Identifier:      PolicePlus Version:
>   ??? (???) Code Type:       ARM
>   (Native) Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2011-01-04
>   21:07:58.413 -0500 OS Version:
>   iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148) Report
>   Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS
>   (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x04680600
>   Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 Crashed: 0   libobjc.A.dylib 
>    0x34a80466 0x34a7d000 + 13414 1   iAd
>    0x312873e0 0x31281000 + 25568 2
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35825cfc 0x357da000 + 310524 3
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35825bce 0x357da000 + 310222 4
>   iAd
>    0x3128bbda 0x31281000 + 43994 5
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35823ae6 0x357da000 + 301798 6
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35823858 0x357da000 + 301144 7
>   iAd
>    0x3128b1d2 0x31281000 + 41426 8   iAd
>    0x3128b68a 0x31281000 + 42634 9
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x3583b3fe 0x357da000 + 398334 10 
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x3580f6f8 0x357da000 + 218872 11 
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x3580f6bc 0x357da000 + 218812 12 
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35801f76 0x357da000 + 163702 13 
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35801c80 0x357da000 + 162944 14 
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35801b88 0x357da000 + 162696 15 
>   GraphicsServices
>    0x320c84a4 0x320c4000 + 17572 16 
>   GraphicsServices
>    0x320c8550 0x320c4000 + 17744 17 
>   UIKit
>    0x341dc322 0x341a5000 + 226082 18 
>   UIKit
>    0x341d9e8c 0x341a5000 + 216716 19 
>   PolicePlus
>    0x0000221e 0x1000 + 4638 20 
>   PolicePlus
>    0x000021b4 0x1000 + 4532
>
> Thread 1: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d30974 0x30d03000 + 186740 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30dda704 0x30d03000 + 882436 2
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30dda174 0x30d03000 + 881012 3
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30dd9b98 0x30d03000 + 879512 4
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d7e24a 0x30d03000 + 504394 5
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d76970 0x30d03000 + 473456
>
> Thread 2: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d04268 0x30d03000 + 4712 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d06354 0x30d03000 + 13140 2
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35802648 0x357da000 + 165448 3
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35801ed2 0x357da000 + 163538 4
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35801c80 0x357da000 + 162944 5
>   CoreFoundation
>    0x35801b88 0x357da000 + 162696 6
>   WebCore
>    0x34bf6124 0x34b3f000 + 749860 7
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d7d886 0x30d03000 + 501894 8
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d72a88 0x30d03000 + 457352
>
> Thread 3: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d7e9e0 0x30d03000 + 506336 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d7e364 0x30d03000 + 504676 2
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>    0x30d76970 0x30d03000 + 473456
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread
>   State:
>       r0: 0x001c83b0    r1: 0x31291948      r2: 0x001c0d50      r3: 0x0000002c
>       r4: 0x000027ff    r5: 0x04680600      r6: 0x001c1700      r7: 0x2fdfebcc
>       r8: 0x344ba47d    r9: 0x2fdfeba8     r10: 0x00000011     r11: 0x34a80455
>       ip: 0x3e459338    sp: 0x2fdfebbc      lr: 0x312832ff      pc: 0x34a80466
>   cpsr: 0x200f0030
>
> Binary Images:
>       0x1000 -    0x3afff +PolicePlus armv7 
>   
>   /var/mobile/Applications/4C059F18-BA33-4163-BE3A-B46DF274E63C/PolicePlus.app/PolicePlus
>   0xd6000 -    0xd7fff  dns.so armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/info/dns.so 0x2fe00000 -
>   0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7 
>   <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26>
>   /usr/lib/dyld 0x3001f000 - 0x30026fff 
>   libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 
>   <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4>
>   /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib 0x30050000 -
>   0x30053fff  ActorKit armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
>   0x30054000 - 0x3016afff 
>   libicucore.A.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib 0x30191000
>   - 0x301bdfff  DataAccess armv7  <6b9b5235b449335ce5c66d53f32004cd>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
>   0x302b7000 - 0x30366fff  WebKit armv7 
>   <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
>   0x30367000 - 0x3037dfff  EAP8021X
>   armv7 
>   <36659ec2b9def7b5798a05327e369247>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
>   0x3037e000 - 0x303cefff  GMM armv7 
>   <2b63c1e1ce647e031a8a491e156f04d3>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
>   0x303fc000 - 0x3051cfff  CoreGraphics
>   armv7 
>   <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>   0x30549000 - 0x3056afff  MobileSync
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
>   0x3056b000 - 0x3056bfff  vecLib armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
>   0x30641000 - 0x30700fff  CFNetwork
>   armv7 
>   <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
>   0x30701000 - 0x3075afff  EventKit
>   armv7 
>   <037c4bb5e2529e6004d0e1f3d95a84cc>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
>   0x3075b000 - 0x3076efff  libmis.dylib
>   armv7 
>   <855aefc263c6c20e6cf8723ea36125a2>
>   /usr/lib/libmis.dylib 0x3076f000 -
>   0x307c4fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7 
>   <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
>   0x307d8000 - 0x307defff  StoreKit
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
>   0x307e6000 - 0x307e8fff 
>   libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib 0x30811000 -
>   0x30813fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7
>   <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
>   0x30821000 - 0x30853fff  AppSupport
>   armv7 
>   <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
>   0x30854000 - 0x30854fff  Accelerate
>   armv7 
>   <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
>   0x3091c000 - 0x30931fff 
>   libresolv.9.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib 0x309bf000
>   - 0x30a48fff  Message armv7  <69cb7cb1d1d7865fc04dc341544174b6>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
>   0x30a49000 - 0x30a71fff  StoreServices
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
>   0x30b44000 - 0x30b46fff 
>   IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 
>   <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
>   0x30c45000 - 0x30c74fff 
>   SystemConfiguration armv7 
>   <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
>   0x30c8e000 - 0x30c98fff 
>   AccountSettings armv7 
>   <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
>   0x30cd9000 - 0x30d02fff  ContentIndex
>   armv7 
>   <247576cb4f1ff8e92650ae3cb4973760>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
>   0x30d03000 - 0x30e14fff 
>   libSystem.B.dylib armv7 
>   <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c>
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x30e16000
>   - 0x30e28fff  PersistentConnection armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
>   0x30e37000 - 0x30f1ffff 
>   libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7 
>   <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
>   0x30f20000 - 0x30f2bfff  libz.1.dylib
>   armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib 0x30f79000 -
>   0x30f8cfff  MediaControl armv7 
>   <874e83896424ebb3afe59a3a59ba4dfe>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
>   0x30fc4000 - 0x31065fff  Celestial
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
>   0x31066000 - 0x31114fff  QuartzCore
>   armv7 
>   <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
>   0x31161000 - 0x31280fff  Foundation
>   armv7 
>   <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
>   0x31281000 - 0x31293fff  iAd armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
>   0x312af000 - 0x312b4fff 
>   libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 
>   <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88>
>   /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
>   0x312c3000 - 0x31306fff 
>   ManagedConfiguration armv7 
>   <27ac7f05482a8aa9977150f34f9be6eb>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
>   0x31307000 - 0x31347fff  CoreAudio
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
>   0x31429000 - 0x3142cfff 
>   ApplePushService armv7 
>   <9d1eb7b11f0f146c941efbab2c055606>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
>   0x3181e000 - 0x318b4fff  AddressBookUI
>   armv7 
>   <45665471fd70b0733b206d8166df74ef>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
>   0x318b5000 - 0x318d5fff  PrintKit
>   armv7 
>   <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
>   0x31934000 - 0x31a26fff  MusicLibrary
>   armv7 
>   <34edbee423aa7e2ea32ad4eed0620b85>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
>   0x31bd9000 - 0x31c02fff 
>   MobileCoreServices armv7 
>   <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
>   0x31c16000 - 0x31c5dfff  MessageUI
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
>   0x31c5e000 - 0x31c66fff 
>   MobileBluetooth armv7 
>   <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
>   0x31c68000 - 0x31c6bfff 
>   CaptiveNetwork armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
>   0x31c6d000 - 0x31d16fff 
>   libxml2.2.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib 0x31d29000 -
>   0x31d2cfff  IOSurface armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
>   0x31d2d000 - 0x31d2ffff 
>   MobileInstallation armv7 
>   <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
>   0x31d46000 - 0x31d4dfff 
>   AggregateDictionary armv7 
>   <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
>   0x31e09000 - 0x31e4bfff  CoreTelephony
>   armv7 
>   <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
>   0x320a7000 - 0x320aafff  ArtworkCache
>   armv7 
>   <1e65b5000a2234b69164e7904fcf826b>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
>   0x320c4000 - 0x320d0fff 
>   GraphicsServices armv7 
>   <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
>   0x320d1000 - 0x320fffff  MIME armv7 
>   <1989502ce4da514314647c6a0098d8e7>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
>   0x33ae9000 - 0x33aebfff 
>   libAccessibility.dylib armv7 
>   <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c>
>   /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
>   0x33aec000 - 0x33afbfff 
>   MobileDeviceLink armv7 
>   <8f2fc7e811bc57f7a09d7df81c329e1a>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
>   0x33b49000 - 0x33c82fff  AudioToolbox
>   armv7 
>   <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
>   0x33ccb000 - 0x33cdbfff 
>   DataAccessExpress armv7 
>   <6767a1e2afbc86a1ec63dd784f5d3677>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
>   0x33cf8000 - 0x33d29fff  VideoToolbox
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
>   0x33d2c000 - 0x33d2ffff 
>   libGFXShared.dylib armv7 
>   <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
>   0x33d30000 - 0x33d31fff  CoreSurface
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
>   0x33d61000 - 0x33d7afff 
>   libRIP.A.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
>   0x33d95000 - 0x33da4fff  Notes armv7 
>   <7d7a3d10a349471cd2757a479d131b31>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
>   0x33dad000 - 0x33dcafff  AppleAccount
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
>   0x340dc000 - 0x34112fff  CoreText
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
>   0x3415c000 - 0x3418ffff  AddressBook
>   armv7 
>   <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
>   0x341a5000 - 0x34526fff  UIKit armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>   0x34527000 - 0x345bafff  ImageIO armv7
>   <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
>   0x345ca000 - 0x34607fff  CoreMedia
>   armv7 
>   <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
>   0x34608000 - 0x3460efff 
>   ProtocolBuffer armv7 
>   <7e279d3b6d1e1fd7dc8c8a883255fa17>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
>   0x34632000 - 0x34636fff 
>   AssetsLibraryServices armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   0x34637000 - 0x34774fff  MediaToolbox
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
>   0x34775000 - 0x34822fff 
>   JavaScriptCore armv7 
>   <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
>   0x34852000 - 0x3485bfff  CoreVideo
>   armv7 
>   <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
>   0x3492e000 - 0x3493afff 
>   SpringBoardServices armv7 
>   <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
>   0x3493d000 - 0x34987fff 
>   libstdc++.6.dylib armv7 
>   <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056>
>   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib 0x34a7d000
>   - 0x34b3efff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  
>   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0x34b3f000 -
>   0x35127fff  WebCore armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
>   0x3520f000 - 0x352fcfff 
>   libiconv.2.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib 0x353e7000 -
>   0x353ecfff  MobileKeyBag armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
>   0x3549d000 - 0x354d5fff 
>   libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7 
>   <374bd566263e8929c10d50d6a6a48a46>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
>   0x35553000 - 0x35560fff  OpenGLES
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
>   0x355ac000 - 0x355b5fff  WebBookmarks
>   armv7 
>   <9f1760206eaef20c605c5d98e45c823e>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
>   0x355b6000 - 0x355bcfff 
>   liblockdown.dylib armv7 
>   <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9>
>   /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib 0x356d2000
>   - 0x357d9fff  CoreData armv7  <29b1ab7d339e42a6ff6923e54cf43e7b>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
>   0x357da000 - 0x358c0fff 
>   CoreFoundation armv7 
>   <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   0x358c1000 - 0x358f4fff  QuickLook
>   armv7 
>   <8c54395accc7ffc84766ff3e9b24beb1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
>   0x35915000 - 0x35948fff  iCalendar
>   armv7 
>   <6eb50e720d642f5ac510a36989b276b2>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
>   0x35992000 - 0x3599ffff 
>   libbsm.0.dylib armv7 
>   <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2>
>   /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib 0x359a0000 -
>   0x359a9fff  ITSync armv7 
>   <87d409553f90e41a01afce047dc2e8fe>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
>   0x35b60000 - 0x35babfff  libBLAS.dylib
>   armv7 
>   <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
>   0x35bac000 - 0x35e46fff 
>   libLAPACK.dylib armv7 
>   <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
>   0x35e48000 - 0x35e4efff  IAP armv7 
>   <134f59ad5bb91bab6a5fe21b6f36dc8b>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
>   0x35e4f000 - 0x35f5efff  MediaPlayer
>   armv7 
>   <9337abd4fdd749473efaefe64ee649a0>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
>   0x35fca000 - 0x35fd2fff  MobileWiFi
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
>   0x35fe4000 - 0x35fe7fff  CertUI armv7 
>   <5f37446c6b65a8c38ab6233c2e33da66>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
>   0x3601b000 - 0x3603afff  Bom armv7 
>   <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
>   0x3603b000 - 0x3603cfff  DataMigration
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
>   0x3603d000 - 0x360acfff  ProofReader
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
>   0x3612f000 - 0x36137fff  libkxld.dylib
>   armv7 
>   <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac>
>   /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
>   0x36138000 - 0x3616ffff  Security
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
>   0x36170000 - 0x361bdfff 
>   libsqlite3.dylib armv7 
>   <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4>
>   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib 0x361be000 -
>   0x361f8fff  IOKit armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
>   0x361f9000 - 0x3622ffff  CoreLocation
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
>   0x3623f000 - 0x3627efff 
>   libGLImage.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [symbolicating the crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)?